# Shapefile for Eastern Boundary Current

Tags: data, ocean

I'm looking for shapefiles that delineate ocean current boundaries: specifically one for the Pacific Eastern Boundary current. This is for masking marine productivity raster data onto the current feature in ESRI.

Anybody have experience with this sort of thing?

Comment: I think the people that know data the best are those at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Similar to this question [Free ocean currents polyline/shapefile download?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11300/free-ocean-currents-polyline-shapefile-download) which has also migrated to [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Sea Areas shapefile from  [marineregions.org](http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php#iho):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/) have great worldwide shapefiles of oceans and oceans depth (Bathymetry),amongst other great open earth data.[image]